# Unable to lift the sails.js app

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I am unable to run my sails.js app. When I tried `sails lift`, it throws the following error. Is there anything else need to be done?

```
C:\my_project_path\config\._blueprints.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at C:\Users\Raghav Mac\Desktop\FiZZ\web-service-master\node_modules\include-all\index.js:129:29
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at requireAll (C:\Users\Raghav Mac\Desktop\FiZZ\web-service-master\node_modules\include-all\index.js:44:9)
    at buildDictionary (C:\Users\Raghav Mac\Desktop\FiZZ\web-service-master\node
_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-build-dictionary\index.js:68:14)
    at Function.module.exports.aggregate (C:\Users\Raghav Mac\Desktop\FiZZ\web-service-master\node_modules\sails\node_modules\sails-build-dictionary\index.js:190:9)
    at Array.loadOtherConfigFiles [as 0] (C:\Users\Raghav Mac\Desktop\FiZZ\web-s
ervice-master\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\moduleloader\index.js:164:27)
    at C:\Users\Raghav Mac\Desktop\FiZZ\web-service-master\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:484:38
    at _each (C:\Users\Raghav Mac\Desktop\FiZZ\web-service-master\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:46:13)
    at Object.async.auto (C:\Users\Raghav Mac\Desktop\FiZZ\web-service-master\node_modules\sails\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:455:9)
    at Hook.loadUserConfig (C:\Users\Raghav Mac\Desktop\FiZZ\web-service-master\node_modules\sails\lib\hooks\moduleloader\index.js:160:13)
```

Need help with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a brand new app that has never been run before? What version of Node are you using?

Comment: yes, it is.Am trying to run it first time. Node - v0.10.31

Comment: Upgrade to node v0.11.. that might fix the issue, i'm pretty certain the latest version of sails only works with v0.11 or later.

Comment: Thanks a lot Adam. It works!!! If possible, can you post it as answer so that i can upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Adam William Larson for the answer.

**Upgrade to node v0.11.. that might fix the issue, i'm pretty certain the latest version of sails only works with v0.11 or later.**